# Packaging a library with Autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I'm starting out with Autotools, and I'm trying to package a library (a generic stack implementation for learning purposes) along with some usage examples.

The library source lives in `src` and the example in `examples`.

I have the following `Makefile.am`:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libstack.la
libstack_la_SOURCES = src/stack.c    

check_PROGRAMS = example/stack
example_stack_SOURCES = example/stack.c
example_stack_LDADD = libstack.la
```

As long as my understanding goes, I need to specify a header for `libstack.la`, and include that from my example, but I get the following error when running `autoreconf` after adding `libstack_la_HEADERS = src/stack.h` to `Makefile.am`:

```
$ autoreconf -iv
... (omiting irrelevant parts)
Makefile.am:3: error: 'libstack_la_HEADERS' is used but 'libstack_ladir' is undefined
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I couldn't find any information related to the `dir` prefix.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

To handle header of library you should write something like this:

```
libstackincludedir = $(includedir)/my_mega_stack
libstackinclude_HEADERS = stack.h
```